# Lee y escribe las tareas en ruby

Tags: ruby

crear dos métodos: **`load_tasks`**

load_tasks recibe el nombre de un archivo y debe retornar un arreglo de hashes con la información que se encuentra en el archivo. El formato del archivo es:

- 1,Hacer tareas,true
- 2,Lavar ropa,false

El método debería retornar:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: "Hacer tareas", done: true },
  { id: 2, name: "Lavar ropa", done: false }
]
```

Nota: Si el archivo no existe o es vacío debe retornar un arreglo vacío.
save_tasks recibe dos parámetros: el nombre del archivo y un arreglo de hashes con las tareas que debe escribir en el archivo. Por ejemplo:

esto es lo que estoy haciendo

```
def load_tasks(file)

  IO.read(file)
  if File.file?(file) == 1,Hacer tareas,true 2,Lavar ropa,false
  return
    array = []
    hash1 = { id: 1, name: "Hacer tareas", done: true }
    hash2 = { id: 2, name: "Lavar ropa", done: false }
    array.push(hash1,hash2)

  else File.file?(file) == false
    return array =[]
  end
end
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: def load_tasks(file)
  
  IO.read(file)
  if File.file?(file) == true
  return
    array = []
    hash1 = { id: 1, name: "Hacer tareas", done: true }
    hash2 = { id: 2, name: "Lavar ropa", done: false }
    array.push(hash1,hash2)
 
  else File.file?(file) == false
    return array =[]
  end
end

Comment: No lo agregues como un comentario.  Agregalo a tu pregunta.  Presiona `editar`.

Comment: ¿Pero cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: Quieres que resolvamos por ti el problema o realmente tienes un error donde no puedes avanzar? 
(me gustaria ayudarte pero con lo que proporcionas me es dificil ayudarte)

Comment: lo he intentado de varias formas y no me funciona

Answer (score 0):

Creo que has entendido el formato de archivo de manera muy literal, yo imagino que debe de ser algo como:

{número_id},{tarea},{hecho?}

Siendo el primero un número entero, el segundo una cadena y el tercero un valor booleano {true, false}.
Te dejo aquí algunas pistas de una posible implementación de los métodos, asumiendo lo que acabo de comentar.

Así, podríamos crear el primer método como:

```
def load_tasks(file)
lineas = File.readlines(file) #lectura del fichero de texto por líneas
sol = []
lineas.each do |linea|
 ind = 0 # variable de índice en la línea
 linea.each_char do |car|
  if car == ','  
   return "Error, formato incorrecto: primero se debe introducir un número entero" if ind == 0
   hash = { "id" => linea[0,ind].to_i, "name" => "", "done"=> "" }
   sol.push(hash)
   ind = 0 # reseteamos índice
   break # salida de la línea actual
  end
 ind += 1 
 end  
end
return sol
end

p load_tasks("contenido.txt") #probado con la misma entrada que das de ejemplo
```

El código daría la siguiente salida:
=>
[{"id"=>1, "name"=>"", "done"=>""}, {"id"=>2, "name"=>"", "done"=>""}]

Así quedaría procesado el primer campo "id".
De manera similar se podrían procesar los siguientes campos.
Buena técnica sería encapsularlos en diferentes métodos, por ejemplo el primer argumento podría ser un método llamado leer_numero que leyera el número hasta la coma, luego vendría otro: leer_cadena que podía leer la tarea hasta la coma, y de la mimsa manera el tercer campo.

El segundo método pedido es bastante más elemental, una manera simple de hacerlo podría ser:

```
File.open(fichero, "w") do |file|
 file.write(sol[0].["id"].to_s)
end
```

Suponemos que fichero contiene el nombre del fichero y en array sol están los hashes a guardar.
Con el código anterior, hubieramos escrito del primer elemento del array sol, que es un hash, el valor asoiciado al campo "id" (siguiendo con el ejemplo, sería un "1").
Basta modificar el código para que se recorran todos los elementos del array y se escriban todos los campos de los hash, separados por comas en el fichero.
Espero te sea de ayuda. Salud